# Google Cloud Engine is there a way to determine project, instance, and zone of instance from command line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I have a java application running on GCE and I want that application to be able to trigger snapshots of the disks that are on that instance.

I was hoping this information could just be queried from the environment, however I haven't been able to find anything useful besides manually passing this information into a startup script and storing it in a properties file.

I feel like this is a reasonable thing people would want to do.

Is there a way I can query these parameters from the local instance environment so I can then use them in a gcloud compute query?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally a command line utility where I could just go 

# create-snapshot /dev/sdb1

is what I am ultimately looking to emulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always query information to the metadata server as explained in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#default

Additionally if the account authenticated by “gcloud auth login” has the appropriate permissions you can use directly the gcloud command to find specific data.

i.e.  “gcloud compute instances list” will display all your instances including the zone
“gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE –zone ZONE”  will list the attached disks 
“gcloud compute disks list” will list all the disks in your project including the zone they belong to.
“gcloud config list” will display the project name.

Having that information you can take the snapshot. Otherwise you can do what you have mentioned or use APIs

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a more direct way of doing this, but I see that there is enough in the API for me to write a script which does this. Hopefully once done it's something others can use.

Cheers